# Trying to open and close a Modal in different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I am using a Material UI Dialog Form between two components. In the parent component that is Productos.js, I open the component and the child component EditarProductos.js receives the open state from its parent.

I am having trouble because I can only open the dialog once and then I can't open it again.

Below is the code from Productos.js (parent component)

```
//Code...

import EditarProductos from './EditarProductos';

//Code...

function Productos(props) {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

//Code...

function editar(producto){

//Code...

setOpen(true);

}

//Code...

return (

<div>

{id && nombre && precioCompra && precioVenta && cantidad && open &&

<EditarProductos productoEdit={id} productoNombre={nombre} productoPrecioCompra ={precioCompra}

productoPrecioVenta = {precioVenta} productoCantidad = {cantidad} isOpen = {open}/>

}

<br />

//Code...

<br />

<Table className={classes.table}>

<TableHead>

<TableRow>

//Code...

</TableRow>

</TableHead>

<TableBody>

{productos.map((producto) =>

<TableRow className="data-row">

<StyledTableCell>{producto.id
}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>{producto.nombre}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>{producto.precio_compra}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>{producto.precio_venta}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>{producto.cantidad}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>{producto.categorias_id}</StyledTableCell>

<StyledTableCell>

<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => editar(producto)}>

<EditIcon />

</Button>

<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => eliminar(producto)} ><DeleteIcon /> </Button>

</StyledTableCell>

</TableRow>

)}

</TableBody>

</Table>

</div>

);

}

export default Productos;
```

Below is EditarProdutos.js (child component)

```
import {Button, TextField, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogContentText, DialogTitle} from '@material-ui/core';

function EditarProductos(props){

var abierto = props.isOpen;

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(abierto);

const handleClose = () => {

abierto = false;

};

//Code...

return (

<div>

<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">

<DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Editar</DialogTitle>

//Code...

<Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">

Cancelar

</Button>

//Code...

</DialogActions>

</Dialog>

</div>

);

}

export default EditarProductos;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is the internal state that `EditarProductos` component holds.

The idiomatic and easy solution for this would be, that you pass down the `isOpen` flag and the `handleClose` method from the parent, the `EditarProductos` wouldn't have an internal state, just use the props:

```
function EditarProductos(props){
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={props.isOpen} onClose={props.handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Editar</DialogTitle>

        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.handleClose} color="primary">
           Cancelar
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EditarProductos;
```

And in your `Productos` component you need to define a `handleClose` method as well (with `setOpen(false)`) and you need to pass down that too with `isOpen`